# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with known good framework.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

XCode 7.2.1 
iOS 9.2 SDK

I compiled Mobile VLC Kit into a .framework for all architectures quite some time ago and have been successfully using it in one project with no issues. Now I want to use it in a new project and I'm unable to build due to error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" referencing pretty much every function in VLC.

This is a mixed swift/objective C project however I'm not referencing VLCKit from the swift side. The only think referencing VLC is legacy objective C code that has been working fine with this framework in another project.

- Target memberships are correct.
- Framework search paths are set and verified correct
- Build Active Architecture only yes/no doesn't make any difference
- 32bit Simulator (iPhone 4S) and 64bit Simulator (iPhone6) show same problem.
- Problem seems to happen wherever I import the framework, even if I'm not calling any methods on it. Even if I remove the Objective C classes that use VLC Kit and ONLY impo
- I tried copying the framework into the project rather than referencing it but it doesn't make a difference.
- Compared settings from previous project and I can't see any difference.
- Framework is in "Link Binaries with Libraries" list.

I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a ***ton*** of time with the same error. It all boiled down to not having a Host Application set for my Unit Test and "Allow testing Host Application APIs" wasn't checked. Once I set it like in the image, it finally stopped producing errors. Hopefully this is the solution for you as well.

[image: Set your Host Application to your app, and check off Allow testing Host Application APIs]

Comment: It seems mine already has it checked unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.